ffmpeg doesn't have access to qsv nor vulkan
I'm running gentoo, and I have media-libs/oneVPL-intel-gpu installed, and latest mesa drivers, and intel gmm, however, qsv refuses to transcode and gives me the following error everytime
ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -i input.avi -vf hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv -c:v h264_qsv -b:v 5M -maxrate 5M output.mp4
.
.
.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5634ca3e9b40] Error creating a MFX session: -9.
Device creation failed: -1313558101.
Failed to set value 'qsv=hw' for option 'init_hw_device': Unknown error occurred
Error parsing global options: Unknown error occurred

The command I used was copied and pasted as is from ffmpeg hwaccel page. Vulkan also is sketchy, and works 50% of the time only.
What do you think I should do to get full "gpu" hardware acceleration?
Edit:
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 6.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 14 (Gentoo 14.1.1_p20240518 p1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-6.1.1-r6/html --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --cc=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc --cxx=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ --ar=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar --nm=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-nm --strip=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-strip --ranlib=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib --pkg-config=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-pkg-config --optflags='-O2 -pipe -O3 -pipe -march=x86-64-v3 -mtune=skylake -ggdb3' --disable-static --disable-libaribcaption --enable-avfilter --disable-stripping --disable-optimizations --disable-libcelt --enable-version3 --disable-indev=oss --disable-indev=jack --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=oss --disable-outdev=sndio --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-bzlib --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-debug --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --disable-gmp --enable-gpl --disable-hardcoded-tables --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-lzma --enable-network --enable-opencl --disable-openssl --enable-postproc --disable-libsmbclient --enable-ffplay --enable-sdl2 --enable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-vulkan --enable-xlib --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm --enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-zlib --disable-libcdio --disable-libiec61883 --disable-libdc1394 --disable-libcaca --disable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libpulse --enable-libdrm --disable-libjack --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-libjxl --enable-libbluray --disable-libgme --disable-libgsm --disable-libaribb24 --disable-libmodplug --enable-libopus --enable-libvpl --disable-libilbc --enable-librtmp --disable-libssh --disable-libspeex --disable-libsrt --enable-librsvg --disable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --disable-libzvbi --disable-appkit --enable-libbs2b --disable-chromaprint --disable-cuda-llvm --disable-libflite --disable-fontconfig --disable-frei0r --disable-libfribidi --disable-libglslang --enable-ladspa --enable-lcms2 --disable-libass --enable-libplacebo --disable-libtesseract --disable-lv2 --enable-librubberband --disable-libshaderc --enable-libfreetype --enable-libharfbuzz --disable-libvidstab --disable-libvmaf --disable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libsoxr --enable-pthreads --disable-amf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libkvazaar --disable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame --disable-libopenh264 --enable-librav1e --disable-libsnappy --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --disable-libtwolame --enable-libwebp--enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-neon --disable-vfp --disable-vfpv3 --disable-armv8 --disable-dotprod --disable-i8mm --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-altivec --disable-vsx --disable-power8 --enable-pic --cpu=x86-64-v3 --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --enable-manpages
libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100

$ cpuinfo
Python Version: 3.12.4.final.0 (64 bit)
Cpuinfo Version: 9.0.0
Vendor ID Raw: GenuineIntel
Hardware Raw:
Brand Raw: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Hz Advertised Friendly: 3.4000 GHz
Hz Actual Friendly: 3.4000 GHz
Hz Advertised: (3400000000, 0)
Hz Actual: (3400005000, 0)
Arch: X86_64
Bits: 64
Count: 8
Arch String Raw: x86_64
L1 Data Cache Size: 131072
L1 Instruction Cache Size: 131072
L2 Cache Size: 1048576
L2 Cache Line Size: 256
L2 Cache Associativity: 6
L3 Cache Size: 8388608
Stepping: 3
Model: 94
Family: 6
Processor Type:
Flags: 3dnowprefetch, abm, acpi, adx, aes, aperfmperf, apic, arat, arch_capabilities, arch_perfmon, art, avx, avx2, bmi1, bmi2, bts, clflush, clflushopt, cmov, constant_tsc, cpuid, cpuid_fault, cx16, cx8, de, ds_cpl, dtes64, dtherm, dts, epb, ept, ept_ad, erms, est, f16c, flexpriority, flush_l1d, fma, fpu, fsgsbase, fxsr, ht, hwp, hwp_act_window, hwp_epp, hwp_notify, ibpb, ibrs, intel_pt, invpcid, lahf_lm, lm, mca, mce, md_clear, mmx, monitor, movbe, mpx, msr, mtrr, nonstop_tsc, nopl, nx, osxsave, pae, pat, pbe, pcid, pclmulqdq, pdcm, pdpe1gb, pebs, pge, pln, pni, popcnt, pse, pse36, pti, pts, rdrand, rdrnd, rdseed, rdtscp, rep_good, sdbg, sep, sgx, smap, smep, smx, ss, ssbd, sse, sse2, sse4_1, sse4_2, ssse3, stibp, syscall, tm, tm2, tpr_shadow, tsc, tsc_adjust, tsc_deadline_timer, tscdeadline, vme, vmx, vnmi, vpid, x2apic, xgetbv1, xsave, xsavec, xsaveopt, xsaves, xtopology, xtpr

$ vainfo
Trying display: wayland
Trying display: x11
libva info: VA-API version 1.21.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib64/va/drivers/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_21
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.21 (libva 2.21.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 24.2.4 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD

$ vpl-inspect -f
libva info: VA-API version 1.21.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib64/va/drivers/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_21
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0

Warning - no implementations found by MFXEnumImplementations()

$ emerge -s media-libs/oneVPL-intel-gpu

[ Results for search key : media-libs/oneVPL-intel-gpu ]
Searching...

*  media-libs/oneVPL-intel-gpu
Latest version available: 24.2.2
Latest version installed: 24.2.2
Size of files: 8,847 KiB
Homepage:      https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneVPL-intel-gpu
Description:   oneAPI Video Processing Library Intel GPU implementation
License:       MIT

This is the ffmpeg package use flags setup on my system. For those who don't know, use flags are upper system configuration settings per package that affects how the package is built from source, because gentoo is a source based distribution. Anything on the left side is added to the configuration of ffmpeg as long as it has a + sign on it's left.
* Found these USE flags for media-video/ffmpeg-6.1.1-r6:
U I
+ + X                      : Add support for X11
- - abi_x86_32             : 32-bit (x86) libraries
+ + alsa                   : Add support for media-libs/alsa-lib (Advanced Linux Sound
Architecture)
- - amf                    : Enables support for AMD's Advanced Media Framework (AMF)
+ + amr                    : Enables Adaptive Multi-Rate Audio support
+ + amrenc                 : Enables Adaptive Multi-Rate Audio encoding support with
media-libs/vo-amrwbenc.
+ + bluray                 : Enable playback of Blu-ray filesystems
+ + bs2b                   : Enables media-libs/libbs2b based Bauer stereo-to-binaural filter.
+ + bzip2                  : Enable bzip2 compression support
- - cdio                   : Enables audio CD grabbing with dev-libs/libcdio.
- - chromaprint            : Enables audio fingerprinting support with media-libs/chromaprint.
- - chromium               : Builds libffmpeg.so to enable media playback in Chromium-based
browsers like Opera and Vivaldi.
- - codec2                 : Enables codec2 low bit rate speech codec support via
media-libs/codec2.
+ + cpu_flags_x86_3dnow    : Use the 3DNow! instruction set
+ + cpu_flags_x86_3dnowext : Use the Enhanced 3DNow! instruction set
+ + cpu_flags_x86_aes      : Enable support for Intel's AES instruction set (AES-NI)
+ + cpu_flags_x86_avx      : Adds support for Advanced Vector Extensions instructions
+ + cpu_flags_x86_avx2     : Adds support for Advanced Vector Extensions 2 instructions
+ + cpu_flags_x86_fma3     : Use the Fused Multiply Add 3 instruction set ([fma] in cpuinfo)
+ + cpu_flags_x86_fma4     : Use the Fused Multiply Add 4 instruction set
+ + cpu_flags_x86_mmx      : Use the MMX instruction set
+ + cpu_flags_x86_mmxext   : Use the Extended MMX instruction set (a subset of SSE) ([mmxext] or
[sse] in cpuinfo)
+ + cpu_flags_x86_sse      : Use the SSE instruction set
+ + cpu_flags_x86_sse2     : Use the SSE2 instruction set
+ + cpu_flags_x86_sse3     : Use the SSE3 instruction set ([pni] in cpuinfo, NOT ssse3)
+ + cpu_flags_x86_sse4_1   : Enable SSE4.1 instruction support
+ + cpu_flags_x86_sse4_2   : Enable SSE4.2 instruction support
+ + cpu_flags_x86_ssse3    : Use the SSSE3 instruction set (NOT sse3/pni)
+ + cpu_flags_x86_xop      : Enable the XOP instruction set
+ + cpudetection           : Enables runtime CPU detection (useful for bindist, compatibility on
other CPUs)
- - cuda                   : Enables CUDA-based acceleration. Mostly used for specific filters.
+ + dav1d                  : Enables AV1 decoding via media-libs/dav1d.
+ + debug                  : Enable extra debug codepaths, like asserts and extra output. If you
want to get meaningful backtraces see
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Quality_Assurance/Backtraces
- - doc                    : Add extra documentation (API, Javadoc, etc). It is recommended to
enable per package instead of globally
+ + encode                 : Add support for encoding of audio or video files
+ + fdk                    : Use external fdk-aac library for AAC encoding
+ + fftools_aviocat        : cat's a URL to another one, useful for dumping streams.
+ + fftools_cws2fws        : converts cws files (Macromedia Flash, compressed) to fws ones
(Macromedia Flash, uncompressed).
+ + fftools_ffescape       : Escapes an input string, adopting the av_get_token() escaping logic.
+ + fftools_ffeval         : A simple expression evalutor.
+ + fftools_ffhash         : Computes a file's digest using libavutil algorithms.
+ + fftools_fourcc2pixfmt  : Shows the relationships between rawvideo pixel formats and FourCC
tags.
+ + fftools_graph2dot      : A tool to convert a libavfilter graph to a dot file.
+ + fftools_ismindex       : A tool for creating smooth streaming manifests.
+ + fftools_pktdumper      : Dumps packets as demuxed by libavformat.
+ + fftools_qt-faststart   : Rearranges a Quicktime file to facilitate network streaming.
+ + fftools_sidxindex      : Write an MPD file for fragmented MP4 files with a sidx index at the
start of the file.
+ + fftools_trasher        : Writes burts of random data into a file. Great for testing error
robustness/resilience/concealment.
- - flite                  : Adds a text-to-speech filter based on app-accessibility/flite.
- - fontconfig             : Support for configuring and customizing font access via
media-libs/fontconfig
- - frei0r                 : Enable frei0r wrapping in libavfilter
- - fribidi                : Enables fribidi support in the drawtext filter.
+ + gcrypt                 : Enables gcrypt support: Needed for rtmp(t)e support if openssl,
librtmp or gmp is not used.
- - glslang                : Use dev-util/glslang to compile GLSL
- - gme                    : Enables support for media-libs/game-music-emu for playing various
video game music formats.
- - gmp                    : Add support for dev-libs/gmp (GNU MP library)
+ + gnutls                 : Prefer net-libs/gnutls as SSL/TLS provider (ineffective with USE=-ssl)
+ + gpl                    : Build GPL code. Should be enabled unless you require LGPL binaries.
- - gsm                    : Add support for the gsm lossy speech compression codec
- - hardcoded-tables       : Use pre-calculated tables rather than calculating them on the fly. It
results in an increase of approximately 15% in the size of libavcodec,
the main library impacted by this change. It enables savings in table
generation time, done once at codec initialization, since by
hardcoding the tables, they do not need to be computed at runtime.
However, the savings are often negligible (~100k cycles is a typical
number) especially when amortized over the entire encoding/decoding
operation. Improvements are being made to the runtime initialization,
and so over time, this option will have an impact on fewer and fewer
codecs.
+ + iconv                  : Enable support for the iconv character set conversion library
- - iec61883               : Support for FireWire DV/HDV input device using media-libs/libiec61883.
- - ieee1394               : Enable FireWire/iLink IEEE1394 support (dv, camera, ...)
- - jack                   : Add support for the JACK Audio Connection Kit
+ + jpeg2k                 : Support for JPEG 2000, a wavelet-based image compression format
- - jpegxl                 : Add JPEG XL image support
+ + kvazaar                : Enables media-libs/kvazaar based HEVC encoder.
+ + ladspa                 : Enable the ability to support ladspa plugins
+ + lcms                   : Enable ICC profile support via media-libs/lcms.
- - libaom                 : Enables media-libs/libaom based AV1 codec support.
- - libaribb24             : Enables ARIB text and caption decoding via media-libs/aribb24.
- - libass                 : SRT/SSA/ASS (SubRip / SubStation Alpha) subtitle support
- - libcaca                : Add support for colored ASCII-art graphics
+ + libdrm                 : Enables x11-libs/libdrm support for better screen grabbing and
hardware accelerated codecs.
- - libilbc                : Enables iLBC de/encoding via media-libs/libilbc.
+ + libplacebo             : Adds flexible GPU-accelerated processing filter based on
media-libs/libplacebo.
+ + librtmp                : Enables Real Time Messaging Protocol using librtmp
(media-video/rtmpdump) in addition to FFmpeg's native implementation.
- - libsoxr                : Enables audio resampling through media-libs/soxr.
- - libtesseract           : Enables the OCR filter via app-text/tesseract.
+ + libv4l                 : Uses media-libs/libv4l for video4linux instead of direct calls. Adds
support for more devices via the userspace library.
+ + libxml2                : Uses dev-libs/libxml2 to enable dash demuxing support.
- - lv2                    : Enables lv2 audio filter wrapper.
+ + lzma                   : Support for LZMA compression algorithm
- - modplug                : Add libmodplug support for playing SoundTracker-style music files
+ + mp3                    : Add support for reading mp3 files
+ + network                : Enables network streaming support
- - nvenc                  : Add support for NVIDIA Encoder/Decoder (NVENC/NVDEC) API for hardware
accelerated encoding and decoding on NVIDIA cards (requires
x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers)
- - openal                 : Add support for the Open Audio Library
+ + opencl                 : Enable OpenCL support (computation on GPU)
+ + opengl                 : Add support for OpenGL (3D graphics)
- - openh264               : Enables H.264 encoding suppoprt via media-libs/openh264.
- - openssl                : Enables dev-libs/openssl support. Adds support for encrypted network
protocols (TLS/HTTPS).
+ + opus                   : Enable Opus audio codec support
- - oss                    : Add support for OSS (Open Sound System)
+ + pic                    : Force shared libraries to be built as PIC (this is slower)
+ + postproc               : Build and install libpostproc.
+ + pulseaudio             : Add sound server support via media-libs/libpulse (may be PulseAudio or
PipeWire)
+ + qsv                    : Enable Intel Quick Sync Video via media-libs/intel-mediasdk (ffmpeg
versions older than, and including, 5.1) or media-libs/libvpl (ffmpeg
version newer than 5.1).
+ + rav1e                  : Enables AV1 encoding support via media-video/rav1e.
+ + rubberband             : Adds time-stretching and pitch-shifting audio filter based on
media-libs/rubberband.
- - samba                  : Add support for SAMBA (Windows File and Printer sharing)
+ + sdl                    : Add support for Simple Direct Layer (media library)
- - shaderc                : Use media-libs/shaderc to compile GLSL
- - snappy                 : Enable app-arch/snappy support. Required for e.g. Vidvox Hap encoder.
- - sndio                  : Enable support for the media-sound/sndio backend
- - soc                    : Apply additional patches for efficient playback on some SoCs (e.g.
ARM, RISC-V).
- - speex                  : Add support for the speex audio codec (used for speech)
- - srt                    : Enable support for Secure Reliable Transport (SRT) via net-libs/srt
- - ssh                    : Enable SSH/sftp support via net-libs/libssh.
- - static-libs            : Build static versions of dynamic libraries as well
+ + svg                    : Add support for SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)
+ + svt-av1                : Enables AV1 encoding support via media-libs/svt-av1.
+ + test                   : Enable dependencies and/or preparations necessary to run tests
(usually controlled by FEATURES=test but can be toggled independently)
+ + theora                 : Add support for the Theora Video Compression Codec
+ + threads                : Add threads support for various packages. Usually pthreads
+ + truetype               : Enables drawtext filter via media-libs/freetype and
media-libs/harfbuzz.
- - twolame                : Enables MP2 encoding via media-sound/twolame as an alternative to the
internal encoder.
+ + v4l                    : Enable support for video4linux (using linux-headers or userspace
libv4l libraries)
+ + vaapi                  : Enable Video Acceleration API for hardware decoding
- - vdpau                  : Enable the Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix acceleration
interface
- - verify-sig             : Verify upstream signatures on distfiles
- - vidstab                : Enables video stabilization filter using vid.stab library
(media-libs/vidstab).
- - vmaf                   : Enables Netflix's perceptual video quality assessment filter using the
library (media-libs/libvmaf).
+ + vorbis                 : Add support for the OggVorbis audio codec
+ + vpx                    : Enables VP8 and VP9 codec support using libvpx: Decoding does not
require this to be enabled but libvpx can also be used for decoding;
encoding requires this useflag to be enabled though.
+ + vulkan                 : Add support for 3D graphics and computing via the Vulkan
cross-platform API
+ + webp                   : Add support for the WebP image format
+ + x264                   : Enable h264 encoding using x264
+ + x265                   : Enables HEVC encoding with media-libs/x265.
+ + xvid                   : Add support for xvid.org's open-source mpeg-4 codec
- - zeromq                 : Enables net-libs/zeromq support with the zmq/azmq filters.
+ + zimg                   : Enables media-libs/zimg based scale filter.
+ + zlib                   : Add support for zlib compression
- - zvbi                   : Enables media-libs/zvbi based teletext decoder.

$ vpl-inspect

Implementation #0: mfxhw64
Library path: /usr/lib64/libmfxhw64.so.1.35
AccelerationMode: MFX_ACCEL_MODE_VIA_VAAPI
ApiVersion: 1.35
Impl: MFX_IMPL_TYPE_HARDWARE
VendorImplID: 0x0000
ImplName: mfxhw64
License:
Version: 1.2
Keywords: MSDK,x64
VendorID: 0x8086
mfxAccelerationModeDescription:
Version: 1.0
Mode: MFX_ACCEL_MODE_VIA_VAAPI
mfxPoolPolicyDescription:
Version: 1.0
mfxDeviceDescription:
MediaAdapterType: MFX_MEDIA_UNKNOWN
DeviceID: 1912/0
Version: 1.1
mfxDecoderDescription:
Version: 0.0
mfxEncoderDescription:
Version: 0.0
mfxVPPDescription:
Version: 0.0
NumExtParam: 0
Warning - MFX_IMPLCAPS_SURFACE_TYPES not supported

Total number of implementations found = 1


Intel made a huge mess moving from MediaSDK to oneVPL and from vaapi driver to media-driver. It is always sketchy... I suggest you to post the FFmpeg version (and if it's a custom build), post the CPU model, and if you have multiple GPUs. Then install libva and libva-tools, execute vainfo, and post the output. Then build and install libvpl-tools, and execute vpl-inspect, and post the output.

@Rotem what do you think the reason for no implementation found?

According to the following table and this table, CPUs before GEN 11 (like Core i7-6700) uses Media SDK backed. Try installing Media SDK. After installing MSDK, vpl-inspect shows different output.

@Rotem you're correct, I should've double checked. I'm not sure why I was under the impression the new framework would keep backward support?!
I still get errors using qsv after installing the intel-mediasdk however!

Intel has a guid for Building FFmpeg with QSV. I actually built FFmpeg 7.01 in Ubuntu 20.04 two weeks ago. I wanted to test VAAPI and I can't use QSV in Linux, because my CPU is Gen 3 (in general I am using Windows 10...). Note that Intel example is ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i backgroud_1080.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv out.mp4, without -init_hw_device qsv=hw.

@Rotem check on the new edit that I added, and notice that qsv is already setup in ffmpeg. It still doesn't work and it complains about not being able to work in low power mood ... something!!

Do you think FFmpeg tries to use low power mode? Executing ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_qsv shows: -low_power <boolean> E..V....... enable low power mode(experimental: many limitations by mfx version, BRC modes, etc.) (default auto). You may try adding -low_power 0 to the command. You may try encoding only with -v debug: ffmpeg -v debug -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=1:duration=100 -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4. When I try it in Windows 10, FFmpeg 7.01 uses oneVPL and report error code: -1313558101... FFmpeg 5.1.2 uses MSDK and it's working. Note: In Windows it is statically linked.

I used this command for example $ ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i video -c:v hevc_qsv video.mp4 and this is the output I got [hevc_qsv @ 0x55b1ac0d2cc0] Low power mode is unsupported [hevc_qsv @ 0x55b1ac0d2cc0] some encoding parameters are not supported by the QSV runtime. Please double check the input parameters. [vost#0:0/hevc_qsv @ 0x55b1abbbdb40] Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such asbit_rate, rate, width or height. Error while filtering: Function not implemented

@Rotem does the vpl-inspect output I just added mean that the vpl implementation that I have doesn't support h264 or hevc_qsv?

Yes, it looks strange. In Windows, I am getting a long list of codecs (but with Impl: MFX_IMPL_TYPE_SOFTWARE, due to my old hardware). I assumed that oneVPL dispatcher suppose to use the MSDK backend, and that vpl-inspect lists the codecs supported by MSDK. It could be that vpl-inspect is designed for Intel Gen 11 and above (I am not sure).

@Rotem I think I've read in many places that the gen 9 graphics supports many functions. I don't recall any of them at the moment unfortunately as I'm multitasking while checking answers to this thread, so it's kinda difficult for me to search for these resources again. I'm not sure perhaps I forgot to do something while compiling the intel-mediasdk package. Sometimes I have to add extra configuration options manually for functions that are not normally supported.
The only resource I have now is this; https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/766166/onevpl_upgrade-from-msdk_2021.3-766165-766166.pdf
